# How to set Acrobat Adobe Reader DC (>15.023.20053) default zoom to xxx%?

Tags: adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

I am using Acrobat Adobe Reader DC (15.023.20053) and would like to set the default zoom to something like 300%. I applied the available answers by going to `Edit -> Preferences -> Page Display -> Zoom` but nothing happened.

How to change the default zoom setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default zoom factor counts for documents which have set to open in the default zoom.

However most documents have their own setting, which has precedence over the application's default.

You will therefore have to change the document's properties accoringly.